# Is a closed basic 2-form on a principal $S^1$ bundle the curvature of a connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Suppose one has an $S^1$ principal bundle $p: P\rightarrow M$, and a closed 2-form $F$ on $M$. Then the pullback form $p^*F$ is closed, vanishes on vertical vectors, and is invariant under the action of $S^1$ on $P$. These are all essential characteristics of a curvature form of a connection on an $S^1$ bundle, so my question is:

Is there a connection 1-form $\alpha$ such that d$\alpha=p^*F$? As of now, I'm not even sure how to see that $p^*F$ is trivial in the cohomology of $P$.

Comment: This is standard. Every connection is of the form $\omega = \psi + p^*\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, where $\psi$ is the global angular form and $\Omega = p^*F$ the curvature. Also, $\Omega = d\omega  = d\psi + dp^* \alpha = -p^*e + dp^* \alpha$, where $e$ is the real Euler class which coincides with the real Chern class (which is the curvature up to a scalar). You can write this in integral coefficients and $F$ entirely determines the circle bundle with a connection. Take a look at Bott and Tu.

Comment: … There's also these notes http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&ved=0ahUKEwjbzabhx9TPAhUJgJAKHTLhDoQ4ChAWCDAwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780817649586-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-993379-p174035557&usg=AFQjCNFs7t4E8Mn0O1yOwenbNHIBulkiRQ&sig2=e8jZMrngl0Fd2CLUnml4mg&bvm=bv.135475266,d.Y2I that seems detailed.

Comment: I believe the "notes" in the previous comment are meant to be https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4959-3_2, chapter 2 of Blair's book _Riemannian Geometry of Contact and Symplectic Manifolds_

Answer (score 1):

Taking $F=0$ we satisfy those conditions, and your question is then whether there is a flat connection. But then the Chern class vanishes. Taking $F$ some area form, we need a nonzero Chern class. At the least, you need to work out whether the integral of $F$ over every 2-cycle is an integer equal to the Chern number.

Comment: If all of these integrals have integer values, then indeed $F$ is the curvature of some connection, but perhaps not on the circle bundle you started with. If $F$ has the same integrals as the Chern form of your circle bundle, then of course $F$ differs from the Chern form by an exact differential $d\phi$ and you add (a suitable constant multiple of) $\phi$ to your connection form to get curvature $F$.